# Postman- Retrieve specific key values from JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postman

`I got this response from the api call and I need to extract specific values from the response. Also, I want to use it as a pre request script in another api call.

1. How can I extract values of the ids from the Json object?
   2)Is it possible to extract particular value of the id key where key from equals "rahul.sharma@gmail.com"?

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "e7ab9f7d-c9f4-47e3-8d53-6febcfb914",
            "from": "raulsdirect@gmail.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dc5ca34@mailslurp.mx"
            ],
            "subject": "id and sid",
            "inboxId": "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dc34221",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-01T15:43:02.357Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"ltr\">id 23543253534<div>sid 34645656452342342343424</div></div>\r\n",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "F2956A8791EB5E6F6F6E259C112BB13B"
        },
        {
            "id": "8d547247-32d2-4553-b1fe-33b4ca00221d2",
            "from": "rahul.sharma@adtraction.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-243d965dc5ba8@mailslurp.mx"
            ],
            "subject": "Re: saas",
            "inboxId": "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c263f2dc5ba8",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-01T22:20:23.301Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"auto\"><div dir=\"auto\"></div><p style=\"font-size:12.8px\">sid 325sd-df435-3fdgvd435-gdfv43</",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "948B78E301880858EB66ABDE6698450B"
        },
        {
            "id": "446760be-e261-441a-bffe-fa31aa935239",
            "from": "rahul.sharma@gmail.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "10ea0b7b-b5eb-4c0f-908d-39437f2214a71@mailslurp.com"
            ],
            "subject": "Complete your registration",
            "inboxId": "10ea0b7b-b5eb-4c0f-908d-394354324a71",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-02T07:41:41.685Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"color:unset;font:unset;font-feature-settings:unset;font-kerning:unset;fo",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "3A7619478AB69B1F63C99B9716896B1B"
        },
        {
            "id": "79a2c183-5b72-4bc1-98aa-63bf5d52c2e6",
            "from": "raulsdirect@gmail.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2532165dc5ba8@mailslurp.mx"
            ],
            "subject": "Re: id and sid",
            "inboxId": "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dbdf5328",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-02T19:20:44.655Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"color:unset;font:unset;font-feature-settings:unset;font-kerning:unset;fo",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "1ED8849F70CBCBBA6CF3CFEA0ACA66C4"
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "empty": false,
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 20,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "last": true,
    "totalElements": 4,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "empty": false,
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 4,
    "empty": false
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

To parse `json`, in JS there is a native way to do it.

`JSON.parse()`

Example of usage:
`const data = JSON.parse(yourJsonObject);`

then:

`console.log(data.content)` in your case will return:

```
[
        {
            "id": "e7ab9f7d-c9f4-47e3-8d53-6febcfb914",
            "from": "raulsdirect@gmail.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dc5ca34@mailslurp.mx"
            ],
            "subject": "id and sid",
            "inboxId": "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dc34221",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-01T15:43:02.357Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"ltr\">id 23543253534<div>sid 34645656452342342343424</div></div>\r\n",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "F2956A8791EB5E6F6F6E259C112BB13B"
        }, ... 
]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: In the context of Postman, `pm.response.json()` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

as you want to find id of the content with from that equals to "rahul.sharma@gmail.com" and content is an array of object so, you can use filter method of array like this.

```
const result=response.content.filter(value=>value.from=="rahul.sharma@gmail.com");
```

result variable will contain the whole object which match with your email so if you want only id then you can get it by using another map property.

```
const ids=result.map(item=>item.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to JSON object directly but if you want to convert to JS Object use JSON.parse()

```js
//You can access to JSON object, but if you prefer to get JS Object do this: JSON.parse(objJSON)
const objJSON = {
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "e7ab9f7d-c9f4-47e3-8d53-6febcfb914",
            "from": "raulsdirect@gmail.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dc5ca34@mailslurp.mx"
            ],
            "subject": "id and sid",
            "inboxId": "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dc34221",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-01T15:43:02.357Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"ltr\">id 23543253534<div>sid 34645656452342342343424</div></div>\r\n",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "F2956A8791EB5E6F6F6E259C112BB13B"
        },
        {
            "id": "8d547247-32d2-4553-b1fe-33b4ca00221d2",
            "from": "rahul.sharma@adtraction.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-243d965dc5ba8@mailslurp.mx"
            ],
            "subject": "Re: saas",
            "inboxId": "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c263f2dc5ba8",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-01T22:20:23.301Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"auto\"><div dir=\"auto\"></div><p style=\"font-size:12.8px\">sid 325sd-df435-3fdgvd435-gdfv43</",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "948B78E301880858EB66ABDE6698450B"
        },
        {
            "id": "446760be-e261-441a-bffe-fa31aa935239",
            "from": "rahul.sharma@gmail.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "10ea0b7b-b5eb-4c0f-908d-39437f2214a71@mailslurp.com"
            ],
            "subject": "Complete your registration",
            "inboxId": "10ea0b7b-b5eb-4c0f-908d-394354324a71",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-02T07:41:41.685Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"color:unset;font:unset;font-feature-settings:unset;font-kerning:unset;fo",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "3A7619478AB69B1F63C99B9716896B1B"
        },
        {
            "id": "79a2c183-5b72-4bc1-98aa-63bf5d52c2e6",
            "from": "raulsdirect@gmail.com",
            "domainId": null,
            "attachments": [],
            "to": [
                "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2532165dc5ba8@mailslurp.mx"
            ],
            "subject": "Re: id and sid",
            "inboxId": "af09331a-d681-48c4-9075-2c2965dbdf5328",
            "bcc": [],
            "cc": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-11-02T19:20:44.655Z",
            "read": true,
            "bodyExcerpt": "<div dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"color:unset;font:unset;font-feature-settings:unset;font-kerning:unset;fo",
            "teamAccess": true,
            "bodyMD5Hash": "1ED8849F70CBCBBA6CF3CFEA0ACA66C4"
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "empty": false,
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "pageSize": 20,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "last": true,
    "totalElements": 4,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "size": 20,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "empty": false,
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false
    },
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 4,
    "empty": false
}

//Array of IDs of each content object
const arrayIDs = [];
objJSON.content.forEach( c => {
    arrayIDs.push( c.id );
} )

//You can get the object filtering by the attribute you need
const rahulSharma = objJSON.content.find( c => {
    return c.from == "rahul.sharma@gmail.com"
} )

//Then you can access to any attribute. In this case: id
console.log(`Sahul Sharma's ID: ${rahulSharma.id}`)

console.log('All IDs')
console.log(arrayIDs)

console.log('Info of Rahul Sharma')
console.log(rahulSharma)
```